# Prisma modeling many to many

Tags: javascript, prisma, prisma2

Im hoping there's a simple answer to this i'm missing in the docs.

I have 3 models (tables): Class, Lecture, Notes

A Class record can have many Notes
A Lecture record Can have many Notes

My models look like

```
model Class {
   id String @id
   name String
   notes Note[]
}

model Lecture {
   id String @id
   name String
   notes notes[]
}

model Note {
   id String @id
   name String
   // Here's where i get stuck, do i need to declare everything that has a relationship here?
   classId String
   class   Class @relation(fields: [classId], references: [id])

   lectureId String
   lecture   Lecture @relation(fields: [lectureId], references: [id])
}
```

If i understand this correctly, my Notes table will have columns for "classId" and "lectureId" even though only one of them is used per Note record.

If I try to break this apart, and make my own realtionship models...

```
model LectureNote {
   ...
   @@id([lectureId, noteId])
}

model ClassNote {
   ...
   @@id([classId, noteId])
}
```

I think i have the same problem on my Note model having 2 references:

```
model Note {
  ...
  lecture LectureNote
  class  ClassNote
}
```

Obviously, ive dumbed this down a bit for my example - but this gets at the heart of it. Should i just be having the extra fields on the Note model even though only one or the other is ever used? In classic DB design, i could make my own bridge tables (LectureNotes and ClassNotes) and just link them up via their PKs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relational database design question.

As with all design, there's never one answer, but different tradeoffs.

Lets consider the two options your question listed:

## Option 1: `Class`, `Lecture`, `Note`

```
model Class {
   id String @id
   name String
   notes Note[]
}

model Lecture {
   id String @id
   name String
   notes Note[]
}

model Note {
   id String @id

   name String

   classId String
   class   Class @relation(fields: [classId], references: [id])

   lectureId String
   lecture   Lecture @relation(fields: [lectureId], references: [id])
}
```

- pros:

  - Least amount of tables
  - Reuse and interoperability between `Note`s for different entities (polymorphism)
- cons:

  - Unused column in `Note`, taking up space
  - Potential for bug, if a single `Note` row is associated to both a `Class` and a `Lecture` (but can be resolved by adding constraint validation)

## Option 2: `Class`, `Lecture`, `ClassNote`, `LectureNote`

```
model Class {
   id String @id
   name String
   notes ClassNote[]
}

model Lecture {
   id String @id
   name String
   notes LectureNote[]
}

model ClassNote {
   id String @id

   name String

   classId String
   class   Class @relation(fields: [classId], references: [id])
}

model LectureNote {
   id String @id

   name String

   lectureId String
   lecture   Lecture @relation(fields: [lectureId], references: [id])
}
```

- pros:

  - No unused columns
  - Decoupled `Note`s, so they can change independently
- cons:

  - More tables, which can make interoperability harder (e.g. what if we want all `Note`s, regardless if they're of `Class` or of `Lecture`)

So which one best suits your use-case?

Comment: Thanks! I think I’ll end up going for option 2 … it just feels cleaner than having a table with a bunch of unused cols. I’m alittle suprised there isn’t a way to have one nite table and then various join tables

Comment: @empire29 a 3rd approach would be to move the foreign keys into junction tables, which will result in a many-to-many relationship. But does it make sense for a single note to have multiple classes and multiple lectures?

Comment: A Note would belong to one or the other, but not both. I thought of a junction for each pairing (so a LectureNotes and a ClassNotes table) - but i want to say it was adding extra fields for some reason.